# Updating a table based on plot selection by altair

Tags: python, visualization, altair

For the past week, I have been trying to create an interactive altair dashboard. My goal is to create a plot connected to a table, where the table gets updated based on the selection of the plot.
For example, my data is:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,'This is good', 'pos'],
                    [1,'This is bad', 'neg'],
                    [2,'This is ok', 'neu'],
                    [2,'This is good', 'pos'],
                    [3, 'This is fine', 'neu'],
                    [3, 'Bad bad', 'neg'],
                    [3, 'Amazing', 'pos'],], columns=['date', 'text', 'sent'])
```

For plotting the data, I want `x='date'` and for the `y` axis, I want to plot the number of 'pos', 'neu', 'neg' in each date. So something like this:

[image]

I then want to create a table that gets updated based on the selection on the plot. For example, if `date=2` and `sent=neu` is selected, I want to show in the table its corresponding text (that is 'This is fine').

First I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997825/python-altair-generate-a-table-on-selection). I created a second dataframe `data2` that has the data for 'date' and the number of 'pos','neg','neu' for each date.

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'pos',1],
                  [1,'neg',1],
                  [1,'neu',0],
                  [2,'pos',1],
                  [2,'neg',0],
                  [2,'neu',1],
                  [3,'pos',0],
                  [3,'neg',1],
                  [3,'neu',0]], columns=['date', 'sent', 'count'])
```

But then I couldn't use the selector of `data2` to filter the table made from the original `data`.

I also tried to directly make the plot from `data` by

```
base = alt.Chart(data).mark_line(point=True).encode(
x='date:Q',
y=alt.Y('count(sent):Q')
)
```

but this only counts the number of times that each date is showing up in the data set, not the frequencies of 'pos','neg','neu'.

So I wanted to ask how I can either filter the table from `data` by using a selector on `data2`, or directly plot the chart from `data`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can build upon the example you linked and do something like this:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

# Brush for selection
brush = alt.selection(type='interval')

# Scatter Plot
points = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color=alt.condition(brush, alt.Color('Origin:N', legend=None), alt.value('grey'))
).add_selection(brush)

# Base chart for data tables
ranked_text = alt.Chart(source).mark_text(align='right').encode(
    y=alt.Y('row_number:O',axis=None)
).transform_filter(
    brush
).transform_window(
    row_number='row_number()'
).transform_filter(
    'datum.row_number < 15'
).transform_aggregate(
    count='count()',
    groupby=['Origin']
)

# Data Tables
count = ranked_text.encode(
    text='count:N',
    color='Origin',
    yOffset='Origin'
).properties(
    title=alt.TitleParams(text='Horsepower', align='right')
)

# Build chart
alt.hconcat(
    points,
    count
).resolve_legend(
    color="independent"
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
)
```

[image]

Note that this relies on the current development version of Altair from GitHub, which introduces the yOffset encoding. Without it, the colors are plotted on top of each other, and I couldn't get it to work nicely with faceting. If you don't need to offset, you can remove the groupby in the aggregate transform and just plot a single count.