# How can I print the value of a clicked point in altair_viz scatter plot?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, altair, vega-lite

I have created a scatter plot from a dataframe. One of the columns contains large amounts of text, which isn't feasible to display in the hover bubble.

I would like to be able to click on a point and the values in the corresponding row to be printed outside the scatter plot. I don't mind if it gets printed as text to the cell output or to another altair panel.

Basically I'm thinking of a 'context-detail' type relationship, although it doesn't have to be fancy. I just want to investigate specific points on my chart.

EDIT: Some relevant code

```py
chart = alt.Chart(tsne_df).mark_point().encode(
    x = 'x',
    y = 'y',
    color = 'is_query',
    tooltip = ['x', 'y', 'is_query', 'source']
).properties(
    width=800,
    height=500)
```

The `source` column contains too much info for the tooltip.

Comment: You can create a second chart with mark_text and set a transform filter based on the selection as in the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997825/python-altair-generate-a-table-on-selection